# Magento 1.9.4 admin stop working getting "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page." all the time

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on magento 1.9.4 and my admin is stopped working. When I entery username and password all times it is displaying **"Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."**.

I tried by deleting var/cache and var/session. I also delete cookie from database. I clear my broswers cache and session. Still not working. I also setup new database(backup database), But still it is showing same message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this.

In database.

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';

DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_path';
```

And in your /app/etc/local.xml

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>

<session_save_path><![CDATA[/tmp/session]]></session_save_path>
```

It will resolve your issue.

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Hello, I already did it. but still same error.

Comment: Ok, this is general solution so I gave you. I will find something else and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else are using AWS Cloudfront in the front of your Magento application. Your issue can be this two parameters.

Choose which query strings to include in the cache key and Choose which cookies to include in the cache key.

Maybe this values should be whit All and All.